# Retrieve direct message from Slack

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I need to retrieve direct messages (1to1 chat)
I created an APP but I can retrieve only

```
"is_channel": true,
"is_group": false,
"is_im": false,
"is_mpim": false,
```

I used https://slack.com/api/users.conversations and other endpoints without luck.

Comment: Do you mean DM between app and some user ?
What is the error you are getting?

Comment: correct. I don't gen any error, I can't retrieve them

Comment: Have you requested the `im:read` scope and included `im` as a value for the `type` parameter when calling `users.conversations`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve direct messages,
you need to explicitly specify the `types` input parameter as `im`.
types parameter specifies what are the different types of conversations that API should retrieve and provide in response.
By default, if you don't specify any types parameter, then it will show only public channels

Check the parameter explanation [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.conversations#arg_types)